# A Ruby string analyser

Tags: ruby

I wrote this script for a code challenge on TreeHouse. I already submitted my code, but I am looking for an after the fact feedback.

The challenge was to open a file of text, remove specific words (provided in another file) and do the following:

> Output to the screen in a readable fashion
>   1. total word count after filtering
>   2. highest occurring word
>   3. longest word(s) and its / their length
>   4. sort the list from most occurring to least occurring then output that data to the screen as an unordered list
>   5. Bonus: Return the word list in JSON.

I decided to split the solution into two classes:

1. One class to sanitise the string into words only
2. Another class to do the analysis

This is the sanitiser class. Given text it should return a string of words only. It should remove anything that is *not a letter or an apostrophe*, and *compress all white space into a single space character*.

I accept that [this has problems](https://gist.github.com/abitdodgy/e3201365dd8328efbfd3#file-output-txt-L175). For example, I found an instance of an apostrophe as a word. Perhaps it was a leading or a trailing one. But defining the boundaries of a word is a tricky proposition.

```
class WordsOnlySanitizer
  # Allow for diacritics, hence p{Alpha} and not \w
  # We should not split words on apostrophes either
  WORDS_ONLY_REGEX = /[^\p{Alpha}']/i

  # We want to reduce all white space into a single space
  SPACE_ONLY_REGEX = /\s+/

  def self.to_words(text)
    text.gsub(WORDS_ONLY_REGEX, ' ').gsub(SPACE_ONLY_REGEX, ' ')
  end
end
```

This is the analyser class. It's self explanatory. There is duplication in the `longest_words` and `highest_occuring_words` methods. But I'm not sure how to remove this duplication without making the code less readable.

The `html_list` method also looks a little suspect, but I can't tell why.

```
require 'json'

class Analyser
  def initialize(text, filter)
    @words = text.split
    @filter = filter.split
  end

  def word_count
    filtered_words.size
  end

  def word_occurrences
    @word_occurrences ||= filtered_words.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |result, word|
      result[word] += 1
      result
    end
  end

  def highest_occurring_words
    word_occurrences.group_by { |key, value| value }.max_by { |key, value| key }.last
  end

  def longest_words
    filtered_words.inject({}) do |result, word|
      result[word] = word.length
      result
    end.group_by { |key, value| value }.max_by { |key, value| key }.last
  end

  def html_list
    list = ""
    word_occurrences.sort_by { |key, value| value }.reverse.each do |key, value|
      list << "  <li>#{key}: #{value}</li>\n"
    end
    "<ul>\n" + list + "</ul>"
  end

  def json_list
    JSON.parse(word_occurrences.to_json)
  end

private

  def filtered_words
    @filtered_words ||= @words.reject do |word|
      # Downcase so that Hello and hello count as two occurrences
      word.downcase!
      @filter.include?(word)
    end
  end
end
```

### Usage

Here's how you would use this:

```
text = WordsOnlySanitizer.to_words(File.read('words.txt'))
filter = WordsOnlySanitizer.to_words(File.read('filter_words.txt'))
analyser = Analyser.new(text, filter)

puts "Word count after filtering is: #{analyser.word_count}"
puts "\n"

puts "The most frequent words are:"
analyser.highest_occurring_words.each do |key, value|
  puts "  - #{key}: #{value} occurences"
end
puts "\n"

puts "The longest words are:"
analyser.longest_words.each do |word|
  puts "  - #{word.first}: #{word.last} characters"
end
puts "\n"

puts "Word list:"
puts analyser.html_list

puts "JSON object:"
puts analyser.json_list
```

Here's [a gist with all the files](https://gist.github.com/abitdodgy/e3201365dd8328efbfd3). Warning: There are large text files.

Comment: Just curious, what is the problem with defining word boundaries by simple whitespace?

Comment: @Jonah Are you referring to my `WORDS_ONLY_REGEX`? If so, it's because things like `"!'` and `i.` and `ii.` get included as words, when they are not. My intention was to clean up anything that's not alpha, compress all white space into one space, then split into an array. So in a sense, I am doing that. Perhaps I don't understand your question fully, though.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense.  However `\p{Alpha}` would still include stuff `i.` and `ii.`, grabbing them without the period, correct?

Comment: @Jonah yes, and I suppose you can consider that a flaw. This is why I mentioned that defining word boundaries is tricky. My regex also does not account for non-word-apostrophes. So any `'` character is not removed, regardless whether it is an apostrophe or not.

Comment: @Jonah here's a Rubular to illustrate this behaviour. http://rubular.com/r/BpTzjvo2GU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is that you've defined methods such as `word_occurrences`, which do nothing but set instance variables (`@word_occurrences`, etc.). This is a bit redundant, and it would be better to do one of two things:

1. Define all of your instance variables under the `initialize` method. or
2. Take out the `@word_occurrences ||=` part of the method definition.

I think from a performance standpoint, it might be better to take the first approach, since you don't want to have to calculate `word_occurrences` every time you call it as a method. I also noticed that you only use `@words` and `@filter` once, and that's to define `filtered_words`, so you can make things simple by just defining `@words` to be what `filtered_words` is currently. See below:

```
def initialize(text, filter)
  @words = text.split.reject {|word| filter.split.include? word.downcase}
  @occurrences = @words.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|word, result| result[word] += 1}
  @lengths = @words.each_with_object({}) {|word, result| result[word] ||= word.length}
end
```

I've made `@words` the new `filtered_words`, shortened `word_occurrences` to just `@occurrences` (and made it an instance variable so that we're only evaluating it once, upon initialization of the instance), and added another instance variable `@lengths`, which represents a part of your `longest_words` function, a hash of each word and how long it is.

Also, notice that I simplified your use of `inject` to create a hash of word occurrences and word lengths, by using the handy `each_with_object` function instead.

I also changed `=` to `||=` for the part where you're building up a hash of word lengths. I believe this will be better for performance, as you're not re-calculating the word length for words you already have.

You mentioned duplication between `longest_words` and `highest_occurring_words` -- you could solve this by pulling out the part you reused into a private function, which I would call `highest_ranking`:

```
private

def highest_ranking(entries)
  # Takes a hashmap of the form {"foo" => 100, "bar" => 45} and returns an array
  # containing the entries (array-ified) with the highest number as a value.
  entries.group_by{|word, occs| occs}.sort.last.last
end
```

I simplified `max_by{|key, value| key}.last` to just `sort.last.last` -- it turns out that `Enumerable#sort` knows how to properly handle sorting by keys, so getting the highest one is just a matter of sorting the hash and grabbing the last item in the resulting array. (The extra `last` is there for the same reason the `last` is there in your function -- to drop the number of occurrences and just return the key/value entries in the result array)

Now that you have this useful helper function, finding the highest occurring words and longest words is simple:

```
public

def highest_occurring_words
  highest_ranking @occurrences
end

def longest_words
  highest_ranking @lengths
end
```

Finally, I would refactor your `html_list` function like this:

```
def html_list
  list = word_occurrences.sort_by {|word, occs| occs}.reverse.map do |word, occs|
    "  <li>#{word}: #{occs}</li>"
  end.join("\n")
  "<ul>\n" + list + "\n</ul>"
end
```

Instead of starting with list as `""` and iterating through each word/occurrences pair to add onto it a little at a time, you can take a functional approach and use `map` to turn each word/occurrences pair into a string like `"  <li>antibubbles: 4</li>"`, then use `join` to turn the resulting array into one long string with "\n" inserted in between each list item. I also inserted two spaces before each list item so that they appear indented in the HTML. :)

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer. At further glance, do you think that the `initialize` method is doing too much? How would you test something like that? I feels hard to test, to me at least.

Comment: I've bundled this into a gem, taking into account some of your improvements. https://github.com/abitdodgy/words_counted Thanks for your input.

Comment: Your `initialize` method should set up your instance variables -- in this case, `@words`, `@lengths` and `@occurrences` -- and very little else, if anything. A lot of the time you're just passing in arguments, like `@name = name; @age = age`, etc. I think this is a good example of a case where you can do something more complex within the `initialize` method, while still keeping your code concise and readable.

Comment: Happy to help! :)